# Effect of enabled kernel debug mode on Windows Server

Tags: kernel, windows-server-2012-r2, bcdedit, debugger

I have a problem which shows up sporadically on Windows Server (Cannot bind TCP Port but netstat does not show any usage). I think I would be able to look at the kernel structures. For this I would like to LiveKD snapshot the running machine.

In order to do this I would need to `bcdedit /debug on` and `bcdedit /dbgsettings LOCAL`. What I wonder is: what effect this has (besides enabling debugging). Does this affect performance, footprint or stability of the server or is it ‚only‘ a security protection?

(I don’t use bitlocker, secure boot or credential vault on those images)

Comment: What is the port number you're trying to bind, is it just in a particular range or a specific port?

Comment: It is 8443 and not in the list of persisted excludes, the ephemeral range is higher. It happens after a java server on the port is killed (and restarts).

Comment: Your syntax to enable debugging does not appear to be correct.  The default settings which would be used, in the absence of specific settings, are for [serial connections](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/bcdedit--debug) which would not be very helpful for a TCP connection.  As for a performance hit, with kernel debugging, I suspect it would be minimal provided it was a temporary measure.  Considering you are disable security options, in order to enable it, it's not for security protection at all.

Comment: I know I did not show the full syntax, i was not asking about how to turn it on, but what effect it had (besides allowing to attach the debugger)